# missing the package UnityEngine.UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am new to learning how to code with unity (I am using version 2020.3). I have been looking at different tutorials to make my first game and I want to add a score counter for collectable items. all Tutorials that I have watched use the package UnityEngine.UI and I dont have it. I have seen people with the same problem but there werent any good answers. They were saying that you can find it in **windows > package manager** and I do find it and it is installed but I cant use it. This question might be dumb but Im new to unity so I dont know much. thanks in advance!

Comment: So do you get an error if you try to write "using UnityEngine.UI;" in the top of a C# script? Because otherwise I believe the package you mention should be installed by default in Unity 2020.3.

Comment: `and I do find it and it is installed but I cant use it` can you show how exactly you are trying to use it?

Comment: Yes I write "using UnityEngine.UI;" and I get an error. It just isn't there but my package manager says it is. I will try to remove it and install again

Comment: @Doh09 yes, I type in just under the `using UnityEngine;` line. people are saying that I should remove it from the package manager but it says that there are some stuff that depend on it and that I should check my dependencies for more information. idk what to do

Comment: If you look in in the console window in the Unity editor. Are there any errors? Can you show your code?

Comment: @Doh09 there is 0 errors in the console and I dont need to show you the code. i can just make a new C# file with the start and update method and there is still no UnityEngine.UI package. I tried downloading the newest unity version and making a new project but none of that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you i fixed it by removing it from package manager and then re-installing it.

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: can you please explain how to do that. I pressed remove button in the package manager and it didnt do anything, now it is just grayed out. I also went in the manifest.json file and  there is something called "ugui", I think that is the thing that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but with Visual Studio Community 2022 instead of VSCode. It turned out to be the fact that the project path had a percentage sign in it.

So "c://Project%/" would not work. Renaming it to "c://Project/" fixed it.

However my coworker had the same problem and it didn't work for him.